# How do I prevent a javascript function from running when a DOM element from an array is already selected?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have a script that makes gives me a dynamic header depending on which bubble in an array is currently selected. However, when a bubble is already selected and the user clicks on that same bubble, I can't stop the js function from running and it changes the opacity of the header to 0 temporarily. In this case I'd like for the opacity of the header to remain as 1. This seems rather simple but I can't figure it out. [The code on CodePen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwgzVL)

HTML:

```
<div id="bubbles">
<div onclick="bubbles(0); clearInterval(intrvl);" style="background:#da2225;"></div>
<div onclick="bubbles(1); clearInterval(intrvl);"></div>
<div onclick="bubbles(2); clearInterval(intrvl);"></div>
</div>
<div id="bubblecontent">
<h2>Header 1</h2>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function _(x){return document.getElementById(x);}

var ba, bi=0, intrvl;
var bca = [
'<h2>Header 1</h2>',
  '<h2>Header 2</h2>',
  '<h2>Header 3</h2>',
];

function bubbles(bi){
_("bubblecontent").style.opacity = 0;
for(var i=0; i < ba.length; i++){
    ba[i].style.background = "#ccc";
}
ba[bi].style.background = "#da2225";
setTimeout(function(){
    _("bubblecontent").innerHTML = bca[bi];
    _("bubblecontent").style.opacity = 1;
}, 300);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
ba = _("bubbles").children;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function bubbles, add conditional if the bi is the same as previous one:

```
var prev = -1;

function bubbles(bi){
   if (bi != prev){
//           put the rest of your bubbles(bi) code put here
   }
   prev = bi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLElement.dataset` to store variable of active element, set first `<div>` child of `#bubbles` element to `"true"`, at `click` event of `div` element set all `#bubbles` `div` children `ba` `dataset.active` to `"false"`, set current element `ba[bi]` `.dataset.active` to `"true"`

```js
function _(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

var ba, bi = 0,
  intrvl;
var bca = [
  '<h2>Header 1</h2>',
  '<h2>Header 2</h2>',
  '<h2>Header 3</h2>',
];

function bubbles(bi) {
  if (ba[bi].dataset.active !== "true") {

    _("bubblecontent").style.opacity = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) {
      ba[i].style.background = "#ccc";
      ba[i].dataset.active = "false";

    }
    ba[bi].dataset.active = true;
    ba[bi].style.background = "#da2225";
    setTimeout(function() {
      _("bubblecontent").innerHTML = bca[bi];
      _("bubblecontent").style.opacity = 1;

    }, 300);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  ba = _("bubbles").children;
});
```

```css
#bubbles {
  text-align: center;
}
#bubbles > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 24px 10px 0px 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: background 0.3s linear 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#bubblecontent {
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear 0s;
}
#bubblecontent h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="bubbles">
  <div data-active="true" onclick="bubbles(0); clearInterval(intrvl);" style="background:#da2225;"></div>
  <div onclick="bubbles(1); clearInterval(intrvl);"></div>
  <div onclick="bubbles(2); clearInterval(intrvl);"></div>
</div>
<div id="bubblecontent">
  <h2>Header 1</h2>
</div>
```